# Question links do not function correctly when question list is not sorted by "Votes"

Tags: bug, questions, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example question links don’t work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/example-question-links-dont-work)

Recently I was reviewing some of my own example questions and noticed that clicking on the question links just took me to the main proposal page - not to the actual question.

Turns out that it was because I had the questions sorted by "Off-Topic".  When I changed the sorting back to "Votes", the question links started working again.  Changed back to "Off-Topic" and once again the question links just took me to the proposal.

Pretty sure this is not by design...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug (but it's good to have documented here). Since the linked question is not in the off-topic list, it isn't displayed.

Comment: It actually doesn't jump to the post properly even if the linked question *is* in the off-topic list.  It can even be on the same page, but the anchor won't work.