# Example question links don't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, permalink, example-questions

Typing http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming/3311#3311 into the address bar just sends me to the first page.  It's as though the "3311#3311" isn't there.

It doesn't appear to be browser specific:

> Looks like "Newest" is the only page that functions reliably - the rest will work only when the question linked to happens to sort on the first page. – Shog9 (in a comment below)

Changing sorting to newest and trying the link again always works when I've tried it.

Comment: Works for me... What tab do you have selected?

Comment: @Shog9 The default, which seems to be "My votes".  Is there another one that works better for this?

Comment: Looks like "Newest" is the only page that functions *reliably* - the rest will work only when the question linked to happens to sort on the first page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two bugs here:

1. The randomization was causing us to show the wrong page if there were lots of questions with the same rank (which happens a lot now, except on the "Newest" tab as noted above)
2. If you had last selected the on-topic or off-topic tab, it was loading that tab and then trying to find the question, but those tabs filter out some questions so it often wouldn't find it.

We fixed the bug with the first, and made it load the My Votes tab in the second case (which includes all questions).

Answer (score 3):

Reproduced:

1. Select the "My votes" tab.
2. Navigate to Page #2
3. Click the "link" link for any question on that page.
4. Note that your browser has loaded a page that does not contain the question for which you just clicked the "link" link.

Same thing happens for all other tabs... With the exception of "Newest". "Newest" actually bothers to load the page with the question on.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this from a [link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing/2582#2582) from my profile page, if that matters.  I got sent to page 3 of 4, while that question currently is on page 2; this leads me to believe the bug is related to the sorting order randomization.

Testing more links, it [fails](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing/2185#2185) [sometimes](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/2816#2816) and  [works](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing/2527#2527) with others, but appears to always be consistent no matter how many times I refresh or reload (the sort order doesn't change, either).

Comment: This was copied from my duplicate question (now deleted).  I thought it might help diagnose the issue, but it appears Shog9's explanation suffices.