# Area51 links to posts don't work

Tags: bug, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question’s “link” link (permalink) doesn’t appear to work on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/questions-link-link-permalink-doesnt-appear-to-work-on-area51)

It takes you to the page the question is on, the hash is in the web address... but it doesn't scroll down and highlight the post/question/answer like it used to.

Comment: Repro here.  Pretty sure that this is related to the new random sorting.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/questions-link-link-permalink-doesnt-appear-to-work-on-area51