# Profile link to question in Area51 not working

Tags: bug, questions, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example question links don’t work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/example-question-links-dont-work)

> Exact Duplicate: [Example question links don't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/example-question-links-dont-work)

I was trying to find a couple of my questions on Area51 to see if I needed to delete them, but clicking the [link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164/firearms/815#815) from inside my profile, it does not take me to the page with the question on it.  If go into the topic from the front page, then go to the page identified (ie page 2) the question is there then.  This is happening on multiple questions.