# Slug-free question permalinks fail to load the correct page on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, profile-page, permalink

This is related to [Example question links don’t work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/example-question-links-dont-work), but I suspect the root cause is different.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Set your question sort order to "Newest" (since other sort orders are [broken in other ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52594/example-question-links-dont-work) when loading question permalinks).
2. Navigate to page 2.
3. Click the "link" link on any question to obtain and navigate to the permalink URL. Example URL: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking/2259#2259
4. Note that the page reloads, with the proper page and question displayed.
5. Edit the resulting URL to remove the [slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Slug). Example URL: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/2259#2259
6. Navigate to the slugless URL, and note that a page that does **not** contain the question is displayed.
7. (Optional, for extra fun and points!) Edit the URL again, this time removing the *proposal* number. Example URL: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2259#2259 - note that this URL will now load the proper page and display the question!

I suspect this is simply an issue with how URLs are parsed: when the slug is omitted, the question number itself is interpreted as the slug, preventing the site from finding the question (and as a result, the page containing it). This wouldn't be so much of a problem, except that *the question links on [the Reputation tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/125?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) in user profiles omits the slug!*

#### Potential fixes

- Adjust URL parsing to correctly identify the question number on slug-free URLs.
- Adjust the Reputation tab to add a slug (any slug) to the question URLs.
- Hack up the Reputation tab even more, removing the proposal ID entirely and relying on the behavior described in #7 (above) to find both the proposal and page given only a question number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed diagnosis!  We don't send down the URL slug because [some users'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) reputation graphs have gotten quite large.  For now we'll just link to `/{answerId}` which automatically redirects to the correct URL.

As an added bonus, we now include the question title in the reputation graph details.